# Trouble making Bootstrap alert overlay a jumbotron with rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hey I'm still getting used to creating websites and I'm trying to figure out how to create something like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                 <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4>This is an alert!</h4>
          <p>
                 <button class="btn btn-danger" type"button">Danger Action</button>
                 <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Cancel</button>
          </p>
</div>
```

to show up over an entire jumbotron that has been divided into rows. I'm not set on an alert to do this and open to suggestions. I need to be able to put other elements into the alert and if opaque I want to be able to see the jumbotron behind it.

Here is an example of the jumbotron I'm trying to cover:

```
<div class="jumbotron">

                <div class="container">
                <!--Row with two equal columns-->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p> <p><a target="_blank" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Get started today</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p> <p><a  target="_blank" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Get started today</a></p><p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p> <p><a target="_blank" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Get started today</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p> <p><a target="_blank" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Get started today</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the height can be dynamic, then you can just switch classes on the alerts. I changed your html-markup a little bit in order to easier add/remove classes.

Here is a [full screen example](https://jsfiddle.net/Salmin/1b5kod8f/3/embedded/result/)

Here is the [JS-FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Salmin/1b5kod8f/3/)

```
function myAlert() {
    $(".jumbotron").addClass("alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in");
    $(".main").addClass("hidden");
    $(".myAlert").removeClass("hidden");
}

function danger() {
    alert("you just alerted some danger");
}

function cancel() {
    $(".jumbotron").removeClass("alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in");
    $(".main").removeClass("hidden");
    $(".myAlert").addClass("hidden");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is close to what I'm looking to do but I'd like the alert to overlay the jumbotron not replace it.

Comment: I edited my comment and made it the way you want. I believe the easiest way to get the correct height is use CSS to match heights. Right now they are not matching because bootstrap are using different margins/paddings for different classes.